# Display of Stack Exchange on mobile got messed up

Tags: support, mobile-web

I was using Math Stack Exchange earlier today on my phone, when suddenly the browser lagged a bit, I tapped on the screen a couple times, and suddenly the layout of the site changed. It now looks like this:

[image]

I tried closing the tab, my browser, and even restarting my phone, but it won't switch back. I'm not sure if this is due to chrome or to the site, but I couldn't find anything online explaining what happened.

What's more bizarre is the other Stack Exchange sites look how they're supposed to (e.g. see below).

Does anyone know how I can change it back?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you switched to the full site view... there's a link in the footer that will switch it back if that's what happened. It's a per-site setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switched to the full view of the website. At the bottom of the web page, there is a button labeled "Mobile"; tap it to switch back to the default view.

[image]